# How do I convert Bytes to Integers in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, python, parsing, websocket, type-conversion

I'm running a server on Python which sends data to JavaScript. This server however can only send bytes. I'm needing the data to be in integer form. Is there a way to convert this in Javascript.

Here's the line of Code that's receiving the data. How can I transform evt.data from bytes to Integers. What I'm receiving from Python is the b' followed by the number. Example: b'120'

```
ws.onmessage = function (evt) {
                  var received_msg = evt.data;
```

Here is the line of code that is used to Send data from Python. It's UDP and unfortunately can only send bytes. I'm sending data from a python server to python client and then to a python websocket server. That python web socket server unfortunately can't send over the bytes converted to ints via the " int() " method.

```
sock.sendto(bytes(MESSAGE, "utf-8"), (ip_address, UDP_PORT))
```

What do I need to do? Thanks in Advance! :)

Comment: Just to be clear in **Javascript** you are getting a string line `"b'120'"`?  That doesn't seem correct as that's how python *represents* bytes as a string.

Comment: Yes! You are correct, I was pasing it through the "str()" method! @MarkMeyer

Answer (score 3):

Javascript doesn't support 64 bits integers. That said this function should do the trick for 32 bit signed integers:

```js
var byteArrayToInt = function(byteArray) {
    var value = 0;
    for (var i = byteArray.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        value = (value * 256) + byteArray[i];
    }

    return value;
};
```

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers, it only works for positive numbers

Comment: Also, it doesn't handle integers beyond 2^53-1, because that's the maximum precise integer value stored in an IEEE double precision float. BUT, if you need to convert 32-bit integers (4 bytes), the algo is fine for unsigned integers, and if you need them signed, just subtract 2^32 if you get a value greater than 2^31-1

Answer (score 2):

I hope this helps

```js
function binToInt(bin){
 return parseInt(bin, 2);
}

console.log(binToInt("00101001")); //Outputs 41
```

Comment: `What I'm receiving from Python is the b' followed by the number. Example: b'120'` What happens when you pass `b'120'` to your function?